# In this sentence, is "holding" or "carrying" more natural or correct?

Tags: word-choice

Which of 'holding' and 'carrying' would be more correct/natural to use in this situation? Or are they equally correct/natural?

> She got into the cab, holding/carrying a box of chocolates.

Comment: They are both fine and, for all intents and purposes, totally synonymous in this situation

Answer (score 1):

Both "holding" and "carrying" are pretty much equally valid.

"Holding" slightly implies that they are being held against her body, a bit like holding a baby, or clutched in her hand.

"Carrying" on the other hand, implies that they are dangling in a bag of some sort, or perhaps supported loosely on top of her arms.

Comment: Do you mean “lightly” or “tightly”?

Comment: @JeffMorrow  Edited - is it clear enough now?

Comment: Looks fine to me

Answer (score -1):

Hold and carry are very similar and, in this case, basically synonymous.

Carry implies transporting something from one place to another. Hold has no such implication, but doesn't imply *not* transporting, either.

Comment: In the context of getting into a cab while holding/carrying box of chocolates, they have different meanings, and neither is about transportation.

Comment: @gotube Care to elaborate on those differences?

Comment: Mike Brockington did a decent job of it in his answer. We tend to "hold" objects in our hands, but "carry" objects that hang. I *hold* my phone in my hand, but I *carry* grocery bags.

Comment: @gotube Yeah, no.  Google "hold vs carry."  See how many hits you get describing your definition vs how many you get describing mine